# How can I check what a keyboard shortcut is mapped to?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I check what a keyboard shortcut is mapped to?

I'm using Notepad++ with a plugin extension. The plugin says it's got a keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> for an operation ... but it's not working

I suspect a recently installed application has grabbed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

How can I determine what has got the shortcut?

Comment: Are you using right hand side Alt key with a non us keyboard setting. _This works in two modes. Right Alt or Shift + Right Alt + another key and also by pressing dead keys (such as accents). On non US  physical keyboards the Right Alt key is called Alt Gr. Right Alt is the same key as Ctrl + Left Alt on the US International keyboards, and on almost all keyboards except the standard US keyboards where left and right keys are treated the same_.

Answer (score 1):

On the Notepad++, **Run > Modify Shortcut/Delete Command**
then toggle through different headers (main menu, macros, run commands, plugin commands, scintilla commands) to see and change the shortcut settings.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks ... it's useful to know, but my issue is not specific to Notepad++, rather it's a general Windows issue ... I suspect a recently installed application has grabbed CTRL + ALT + M